# ubuntu 12.10 loops with usb error 71 when booting

Tags: 12.10

I am using ubuntu 12.10 with an asus motherboard.
I was able to install the operating system with no problems.
However when I boot the server it keeps looping with usb error 71 even though I haven't plugged any usb devices in to the machine.
I used a live cd to install the operating system.

The errors keep scrolling up the screen making it hard to see the other prompts.
However I can remote in to the machine and not see the errors and do what ever I need to do with the system.

Is there anyway of preventing these errors from displaying on the screen?
I am not interested in plugging any usb devices in to the machine since it is going to be housed in a data center.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the md5sum of the iso file you used to create the install disk.  If that is OK, consider if there is something wrong with the USB header cable or the port - if there's nothing plugged in then it shouldn't be trying to connect.  Don't forget to check the USB ports on the back of the machine.

Unplug the usb header cable(s) and if that doesn't work try to disable the USB ports in BIOS.  You might also perform a BIOS reset.